# Error Code 413: The maximum message size quota for outgoing messages (1114112) has been exceeded

Tags: python, azure, celery, azureservicebus

I am using Azure Service Bus as the broker for my Celery module. One of the messages in my code seems to exceed the 1 MB max message size set by Azure.

I tried to reconfigure the `Max message size (in KB)` to 10 MB

[image]

However, when I go back to the Queues, it still shows the `Max Size` as 1024 (which I believe is 1 MB) and I still get the same error when running the code.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I understand I should try to reduce the size of my message but just wanted to try this out first before I tried to fix that.

Comment: note that the "Max size" in the lower screenshot is showing the maximum size of the queue (not the message) - it corresponds to the "Max size, 1GB" value in the upper screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The standard tier allows a single message size of up to 256KB.
The premium tier allows messages up to 1MB and 100MB with the recent preview (needs to be enabled on the pre-existing queues). Note that your message has some metadata and some overhead so the payload should be slightly less than the maximum.

Comment: Where's the setting to turn on/enable this feature?

Comment: In the portal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging#enabling-large-messages-support-for-a-new-queue-or-topic